# I have written the code to upload the value from textarea of html page to firebase database. But the value is not uploaded to the database

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

var mainText= document.getElementById("mainText");

var submitBtn= document.getElementById("submitBtn");

function submitClick()

{
  var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref();

var messageText = mainText.value;

firebaseRef.child("Text").set("messageText");

}

Answer (score 0):

this code is correct. Problem was with the firebase code snipet they provide. I removed -app from the script and it worked.